# Небольшое непонимание процесса авторизации с JWT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, graphql, apollo-client

Проект строится с использованием React + Redux + Apollo Client + Graphql

Когда нам необходимо произвести авторизацию в базе данных пользователей, нужно добавлять в свой запрос параметр headers и в нем указывать токен (который, допустим, сохранили в localStorage), например так:

```
const client = new ApolloClient ({
 uri: 'http://localhost:4000/api',
 headers: {
  authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.token}`,
 }, 
});
```

Далее, серверная функция проверяет этот токен и "устанавливает" личность пользователя.

Вопрос в следующем: где брать данный токен в случае регистрации (для помещения в headers)? У пользователя еще нет сохраненного токена, но сервер его требует и не пропускает регистрацию, если его не указать. Если в запросе убрать параметр headers, то регистрация пройдет, но сервер не поймет, кто является текущим пользователем.

Comment: По сути токен должен хранить что-то, что указывает на сессию пользователя, а не на сам аккаунт. Например, можно генерировать токен с id сессии.

Comment: @Дмитрий, как же его прописать в headers? Происходит запрос, который требует токен. Токен генерируется и присылается обратно только после запроса.

Comment: Токеном должна заниматься серверная часть, фронтенд должен только хранить токен и отсылать при запросах. Как у Вас реализован механизм сессий на сервере? Обычно сервер, если токен отсутствует, создаёт новую сессию и отсылает в ответ заголовок с новым токеном.

Comment: @Дмитрий, заполняется форма регистрации, нажимается кнопка зарегистрировать, далее идет запрос (без headers соответственно, потому что если прописать это свойство, то потребует токен), приходит ответ от сервера с токеном в data, токен в headers отсутствует. В этом случае сервер не понимает, кто является текущим юзером

Comment: Создаётся такое ощущение, что серверная часть Вами не контролируется, а возможно, что мы друг друга поняли.
Регистрация --[запрос без токена]-> Сервер создаёт сессию (пусть `id = 1`) и токен, связанный с ней --[ответ с токеном]-> Браузер запоминает токен в localStorage.
Вам нужно _реализовать в серверной части_ отправку токена в ответ при регистрации/входе.
При последующих запросах сервер будет смотреть связанные с сессией (по тому же `id == 1`) данные по токену.

Comment: @Дмитрий, все верно, сервер отправляет токен в ответе на регистрацию. Я сохраняю этот токен в LS. Далее, сразу после регистрации, мне нужно сделать редирект на другую страницу. На этой странице сервер не понимает кто является текущим юзером, т.к. при регистрации не было указано свойство headers с токеном, потому что его неоткуда было брать. Видимо я что-то не понимаю) Я говорю именно про регистрацию и последующий редирект

Comment: Я тут заметил, что у Вас ```{ authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.token}` }```, вместо ```{ authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}` }```.
Если сохранение выглядит приблизительно также, то исправьте на `localStorage.setItem('token', значение)`

Comment: @Дмитрий, у меня это было изначально, потом я поменял на `{ authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.token}` }`. Суть в том, что это не помогает

Comment: `new ApolloClient` выполняется один раз?

Comment: @Дмитрий, да. Возможно нужно указывать headers только при авторизации, а не регистрации, но это тоже не имеет смысла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас токен получается из `localStorage` только один раз, при загрузке страницы.

```js
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/api',
  request (operation) {
    const headers = {};
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) headers.authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
    operation.setContext({ headers });
  }
})
```

Comment: немного не понял, можете пояснить?

Comment: Когда Вы создаёте экземпляр `ApolloClient`, сразу указывая токен, он (токен) пустой до регистрации и уже не зависит от значения в `localStorage`.
Код выше обновляет заголовок `Authorization` перед каждым запросом, используя свежий токен.

Comment: спасибо, теперь проходит и стало понятно

Comment: возник еще 1 вопрос. Теперь я вижу, кто является текущим юзером после регистрации, но это происходит только после обновления страницы. Если вывести console.log(this.props) на странице где хочешь видеть текущего юзера, то они покажутся 2 раза (в 1 не будет текущего юзера, а во втором он покажется). Видимо я что-то пропустил в документации, но, возможно ли, чтобы текущий юзер показывался сразу и props не вызывались 2 раза?

Comment: Думаю, что дело в роутере и асинхронной операции. Роутер отображает страницу, приходит ответ от сервера, данные перезаписываются, роутер обновляет компонент. В компоненте, где у Вас роутер прописан можно проверять наличие ответа, либо использовать интеграции redux с роутером.

Comment: спасибо, уже исправил, просто после прихода информации от сервера и записи токена в LS, обновил данные от сервера